# Chrome + Dev Tools poor performance

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

That's the test page for this issue: https://kasheftin.github.io/chrome-vue-draggable-performance/ Basically, it's just 10000 divs + simple drag-scroll plugin.

I'm trying to find the reason of very poor and laggy drag performance.

The issue occurs only when Chrome Dev Tools opened, on any dev tool tab, but only in default, not mobile mode. When I turn on device toolbar (emulate on mobile) the lag disappears. It also works fine on firefox (firefox with inspector works even faster then chrome without dev tools).

Tested on 3 PCs on Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 (fresh-new install, no browser plugins, no any custom settings in dev tools, empty cache, history, incognito mode, 32GB ram / top cpu hardware), Chrome 87.0.4280.66.

Also tried every suggestion from [Google Chrome developer tools works very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913727/google-chrome-developer-tools-works-very-slow), it did not help as well.

https://youtu.be/dOTmIG8MlbY

Comment: For me the problem was a conditional breakpoint that I left somewhere in the sources... After I removed the conditional breakpoint the lag was gone.

Comment: @LuisLimas this was an absolute life safer for me. This was my exact scenario, and it took me hours to debug. The issue wasn't happening in Private Browsing mode, which I couldn't explain. But looks like Private Browsing mode doesn't share breakpoint configurations. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React app slows to a crawl with chrome developer tools open. Works fine in incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573388/react-app-slows-to-a-crawl-with-chrome-developer-tools-open-works-fine-in-incog)

Answer (score 3):

There´s plenty of reasons for this to happen, I decided to post this answer because it resulted useful in the comments, I'll try to complement it overtime every time I find a related issue for Dev Tools poor performance:

###### 1. Conditional breakpoints left in the sources

They can trigger this issue because they might be constantly evaluated, remove them all. In my case, after that, the lag was gone.

###### 2. Google Chrome Updates

Most times, this issue is triggered by chrome updates, try using `Google Chrome Canary` or `Google Chrome Developer`. The fix might already be available on those versions.

###### 3. Remove local overrides

Having too many [local overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides) can slow down performance as it increases the number of files loaded in memory. This is especially the case when you override big files.

###### 4. Disable Chrome Extensions

Some extensions might be the cause of the issue, people had [already reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43467516/1657465) the issue at least for the following:

```
1) React Developer Tools                4) Privacy Badger
2) Knockoutjs context debugger          5) uBlock Origin 
3) Brave Shields                        6) Augury
```